# Augment the array item context in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach

Currently, when using a Knockout `foreach` binding you can access the current index with `$index`.  I'd like to make other, similar functionality available to my inner bindings -- for example:

- `array` (lets me access the array being operated on)
- `length` (length of said array)
- `first` (whether or not the current item is the first item)
- `last` (whether or not the current item is the last item)
- `only` (whether or not the current item is the only item)

You get the idea.  Unfortunately the code that sets `$index` is buried deep within the code for the `template` binding with no apparent way to augment the context.

I'm able to get access to `array` and `length` via custom `foreach` binding that extends the `bindingContext` (I know there are caveats to this re: `destroy` but it works for me), but I can't figure out how to implement the other methods that require access to the "current" item without a custom inner binding that is executed for each array iteration.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: description" />
  <button data-bind="visible: $last, click: $array.push({})">Add Another</button>      
</div>
```

(As we know, neither `$array` nor `$last` exist).  Assume that the `button` element could be coming from an external template with no way to know how to path to the current array (so `$parent.items.push` won't work for me).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could come up with was to create specialized bindings that store context info about the array and current item.

Custom `foreach` binding that exposes context about the array:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.xforeach = (function() {
    var createContext = function(array) {
        return {
            '$array': array,
            '$arrayLength': function() { return ko.unwrap(array).length; }
        };
    };
    return {
        init: ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init,
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var extendedContext = createContext(valueAccessor());
            return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update.call(this, element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext.extend({
                '$foreachContext' : extendedContext
            }));
        }    
    };
})();
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.xforeach = true;
```

Custom `template` binding that exposes context about the item/array:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.xforeachItem = (function() {
    var createContext = function(currentContext, forEachContext) {
        return {
            first: function() { return currentContext.$index() === 0; },
            last: function() { return currentContext.$index() === (forEachContext.$arrayLength() - 1); }
        };
    };
    return {
        init: ko.bindingHandlers.template.init,
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var extendedContext = createContext(bindingContext, bindingContext.$parentContext.$foreachContext);
            return ko.bindingHandlers.template.update.call(this, element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext.extend({
                '$foreachItemContext' : extendedContext
            }));
        }
    };
})();
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.xforeachItem = true;
```

Example usage:

```
<div data-bind="xforeach: items">
    <div data-bind="xforeachItem: {}">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: description" />        
        <span data-bind="visible: $foreachItemContext.first(), text: $foreachContext.$arrayLength()"></span>
        <button data-bind="visible: $foreachItemContext.last(), click: $root.add">Add Another</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally, a fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/magnafides/wkCLd/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use $parent.data() to get the actual array.

For **`$length`**, you can do this:

```
$parent.items.length
```

For **`$first`**, you can do this:

```
$index() == 0
```

For **`$last`**, you can do this:

```
$index() == ($parent.items.length - 1)
```

For **`$only`**, you can do this:

```
$index() == 0 && $parent.items.length == 1
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3sRsm/).

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but this won't work.  `$parent` will refer to the parent object (the page's viewModel in the simplest case), and then you have to know the name of the array to access it.  For example: `$parent.items().length` in my example above.  See http://jsfiddle.net/9953v/.  In addition I want to be able to use the more concise `first`, `last`, and `only` functions to help with verbosity.

Comment: I'm still not seeing how it will work.  I've never heard of or seen anything implicit with KO called `data` (other than `$data` but that refers to the current item inside of a `foreach`).  Go ahead and change `$parent.items().length` to `$parent.data().length` in that fiddle -- it won't work (`data` doesn't exist).  Can you fork that fiddle and show what you're talking about?

Comment: I added a fiddle and edited my answer. I was using `data` generically as the name of the array.

Comment: I know that I can refer to the array by name, what I'd like is a generic way to access the array being iterated over without having to know that.